# persistent volume service for reuseable static files in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

before ask question, Im very new for k8s neither AWS service, oh and also english.
please forgive me if my context are ambiguous or bad-english...

My project is run on AKS, with docker image without static files.
these static files are need to replace in run-time, so currently I place static files onto `fileShare` in `Azure storage service`. and it work lookin well so far.

Now, I need to change K8s service from AKS to EKS.
changing K8s service is quite easy...until i encounted my static files.

First, I thought it will be okay to just use S3 storage class somehow.
but from short research, several of documents are recommended to use EBS or EFS.
I was planned to use multiple `Availity zone` for AKS, so I choose EFS.

After implement EFS, I realized that I cannot upload my static file into EFS storage!
I mean I can just upload via sshd or something else, but EFS storage driver in K8s is create randomly generated directory in EFS services storage.

I still i can manually place static file into randomly-generated-directory. but in this case, I just hope that EFS driver pods are did not recreated.
No I cannot use it.

Now, I realized that EFS is not just fit in my case.
I need help to choose what kind of storage service do I use for read static files with multiple Availity zone and multiple pods?

Thanks.

### Edit

After write question, I realized that my question is quite ambiguous.

My kubernetes version is 1.21
and I followed this document about [instruction for implement EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html)

And it work well, and I can check my EFS have several directory like below

```
./
./dynamic_provisioning
./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-1}
./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-2}
./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-3}
./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-4}
./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-5}
./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-6}
./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-7}
./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-8}
```

Because of my `storageClass` settings.(settings are copy from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/master/examples/kubernetes/dynamic_provisioning/specs/pod.yaml))

Okay, now I need to place my same static files into
`./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-N}`
I can manually place static file into `./dynamic_provisioning/{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-1}` but it does not ensure `{random-generated-dynamic-provision-dir-1}` directory will never change nor copy my static files when new dynamic provision directory generated.

In very this moment, I post original question.
After few more searching, I just change `dynamic_provisioning` method to `static_provisioning`.
(like this)

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: ""
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-{MY_EFS_ID}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapi-lb
  labels:
    app: myapi-lb
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapi
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
---
# 배포 대상.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapi
  labels:
    app: myapi
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapi
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapi
        run: myapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapi
          image:  MY_ECR_LOCATION.amazonaws.com/myapi:TAG
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: myapi-secrets
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: myapi
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
          volumeMounts:
            - name: persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data
      volumes:
        - name: persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: efs-claim
```

After theses settings, there is no dynamically generated directory anymore, and I just put static files into very root on my EFS...
and works now as I expect.

```
[efs_connector@0.0.0.0 efs]$ ls -l
total 12
drwx------ 12 efs_connector efs_connector 6144 Mar 14 03:52 dynamic_provisioning # ,_ dynamically created by storageClass.yml files but not use anymore!
drwxrwxrwx  4 efs_connector efs_connector 6144 Mar  8 06:37 files # <- this files are what i want to serve!
drwxrwxrwx  2 efs_connector efs_connector 6144 Mar  8 06:36 locale # <- this files are what i want to serve!
```

But still in my deep inside, Im afraid what this settings cause side effects, and I cannot find clear explanation about what is difference between dynamic and static provisioning.

Or I might using EFS totally wrong.. I still don't know

Comment: what about s3? most common place for static files with different way to access them

Comment: @Felix I will try to use s3 as you recommended from now. but if another service or I just use efs driver wrong, please correct me :>

Comment: What Kubernetes version are you using? Check this [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/statefulset/README.md/) please. They write from 3 pods to 1 file on EFS.

Comment: Thankyou @mozello. i edit post for more information including k8s version(1.21).
i tried to following above example like your link, and i want just a bit of another..method? usage? kind of..